# How to do "Log(x,y)" in sql server 2005

Tags: algorithm, sql-server-2005

I need to find out how many times to multiply by itself to reach a target value in sql server 2005.

In SQL 2008+ you can do this

```
SELECT LOG(8,2)
```

and the answer would be 3 because 2 x 2 x 2 = 8.

But in SQL 2005 the LOG function doesn't accept a base value.

I'm trying to avoid having to create a custom function to do this.

Thank everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `LOG(8) / LOG(2)`.

This is because `LOG(A) / LOG(B)` is equal to the logarithm of A in the base of B. The base of the `LOG` function doesn't matter (because changing bases is, as we've seen, just multiplying by a constant)

Comment: Brilliant... thank you... I'm not a mathematician but I love learning stuff like this.